# wire output can be used as an inside variable?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, hdl

i am learning verilog and i am doing practice questions on https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki.
one of the questions is:

[image: picture of the question]

so my answer was:

```
module top_module(
    input a,
    input b,
    input c,
    input d,
    output out,
    output out_n   ); 
    
    wire and_ab;
    wire and_cd;
    wire or_out;
    and(and_ab,a,b);
    and(and_cd, c, d);
    or(or_out, and_ab, and_cd);
    assign out= or_out;
    not(out_n,or_out);
endmodule
```

which is correct without any doubt, but their answer is:

```
module top_module (
    input a,
    input b,
    input c,
    input d,
    output out,
    output out_n );
    
    wire w1, w2;        // Declare two wires (named w1 and w2)
    assign w1 = a&b;    // First AND gate
    assign w2 = c&d;    // Second AND gate
    assign out = w1|w2; // OR gate: Feeds both 'out' and the NOT gate

    assign out_n = ~out;    // NOT gate
    
endmodule
```

my question is how can it be possible they use 'output' wire as an 'input' to an assign in the same module? its not reg to hold it value, not that i know if you can do it with reg as an 'output' type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog and SV allow the reading of outputs from within a module.
It is different than VHDL which does not allow the same.

Comment: so i can read the output from the same module that drives it? 
does it matter if its 'reg' or 'wire'?

Comment: Yes, in Verilog or SV an output can be read from within the module that drives the output.  Does not mater if its defined as reg or wire.

Comment: VHDL2008 does allow reading outputs